# Loading related entities with Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

This is my second day with EntityFramework and I have another problem:

I'm saving some kind of configuration into my database. This works well:
This is my class:

```
public class Configuration : IConfiguration
{....
   public ICollection<EmailClassificationPattern> emailClassificationPatterns { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

I get two tables *dbo.Configurations* and *dbo.EmailClassificationPattern*s. *dbo.EmailClassificationPattern*s has 4 entries and each references correctly to *dbo.Configurations* via a field called *Configuration_ID*.

I am loading the configuration this way:

```
var configuration = (Configuration)mycontext.Configurations.Where(x =>
  x.configurationName=="Default").FirstOrDefault();
```

Then I am trying to access the member emailClassificationPatterns this was:

```
    var relevantSubjectList = configuration.emailClassificationPatterns.
          Select( x => x.subjectPatternForMailCollection);
```

But I get a ReferenceNullException because *emailClassificationPatterns* is NULL. Why does enttity framework not load the referenced members? I don't have the possibility to include the referenced member as IntelliSense doesn't provide .Inlcude() (like this:)

```
var configuration = (Configuration)mycontext.Configurations.Where(x => 
       x.configurationName=="Default").Include("emailClassificationPattern")
```

Do I **HAVE** to enable eagerLoading? If yes - how? Is there another way to access referenced members and is there some kind of best-practice?

Best regards

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Include` statement comes before `Where`. This will load "child" entities. Like so:

```
var configuration = Configuration)mycontext.Configurations.Include("emailClassificationPattern").Where(x => 
       x.configurationName=="Default")
```

Comment: Is there another possibility where I don't explicitly have to specify which Child-Memeber-Class should also be loaded? I would have expected that EF recognizes which child-members are needed (based on the code) and loads these element dynamically...

Comment: Nope. You have to explicitly load them. his is also pretty smart because in huge relational databases there can be tons of related child-(child-child-etc.)-entities.

Comment: But...what you can also do is just load the configuration entities and when you Enumerate certain child entities of Configuration these will be loaded on demand (just-in-time) if I remember it right. Google is your friend! Lots of documentation about (eager)loading in EF ;)